# time() разве повторяется?

Tags: php, время

Собственно сабж. time() в PHP повторяется? Сегодня в базе нашёл 3 одинаковых значения...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

а разве не могут одновременно создаться записи?

Comment: @Ale_x, ну да. Верно.. )